# Why I can't delete a workspace in Perforce with this error: "Missing stream '' in stream hierarchy..."

Tags: perforce

I'm trying to delete a workspace in Perforce as admin but I always got this error:

[image]

- Note that Administrators can use the -f option to delete or modify
  locked workspaces owned by other users.
- Note that the missing stream have no name
- Note that the stream project plb2020-02_fond_black_unreal_master doesn't exist anymore. It was deleted before trying to removed this workspace

It looks like something is corrupted.

For reference: [p4 client documentation](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_client.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message gives the name of a specific stream to investigate: `//plb2020-02_fond_black_unreal_master` (or something like that -- please copy and paste the actual text rather than hastily-cropped screenshots of text)!  Run:

```
p4 stream //plb2020-02_fond_black_unreal_master
```

(or whatever the name is)

Check that the `Parent` field is valid.  It can only be blank if you change the stream's `Type` to `mainline`.  If that stream's `Parent` looks like a real stream, run `p4 stream` on that stream and check **its** parent, and so on.  Hopefully you'll be able to find the point in the hierarchy that declares its parent as `''` and fix it.

If there is no such stream, check the client itself:

```
p4 client -f probabili-whatever
```

Does it have a `Stream` field that points to this nonexistent stream?  If so, delete that, or change it to an existent stream.

If neither of those works, then you've encountered a bug that doesn't have an easy workaround.  Contact Perforce technical support so they can walk through a more detailed debugging process and possibly issue a server patch.

Comment: Changing to an existing Stream fix the problem.